# how to update GUI from swingworker which returns two different values

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I have a Java app that uses a SwingWorker to update a label and a progress bar in the GUI and it works nice. However, I'd like to add a feature to this setting.

My swing worker performs a task which has length `n`, and it repeats that task `m` times. Right now my GUI just tells me how many time the task has been repeated, but I'd like it to tell me also at what length of the task we are in. Say `n=300` and `m=50`, I'd like something like:

```
Task 49 is at 248 ()
Task has been repeated 48 times
```

What should I modify in my SwingWorker?

```
/**
 *
 * @author digitaldust
 */
public class Model extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

    private HashMap<String, Number> GUIparams;
    private int session;
    private int ticks;

    Model(HashMap<String, Number> KSMParams) {
        GUIparams = KSMParams;
        session = (Integer)GUIparams.get("experimentsInSession");
        ticks = (Integer)GUIparams.get("howManyTicks");
    }

    /**
     * Actual simulation
     */
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {

        int i=0;
        while(!isCancelled() && i<session){
            i++;
            int ii=0;
            while(!isCancelled() && ii<ticks){
                // this is n, the task length and I'd like to update the GUI with this value
                ii++;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            // this is m, how many time the task has been repeated, and now it is updated in the GUI
            publish(i);
            setProgress(i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return i;
    }  

    /**
     * Invoked when simulation exits
     */
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Experiment session cancelled by user. Closing Session...");
        } else {
            // do stuff

            Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Experiment session ended.");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second type parameter V in `SwingWorker<T,V>` is used for carrying out intermediate results by this SwingWorker's publish and process methods. This could be your custom class. Here is an example based on posted SSCCE (shortened for clarity):

```
class Progress {
    private int task;
    private int element;

    public Progress(int task, int element) {
        super();
        this.task = task;
        this.element = element;
    }
        ...
}

public class Model extends SwingWorker<Integer, Progress> {
    ...
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            ...
            publish(new Progress(i, ii));
        }
}
```

***EDIT: example of process method implementation***

```
@Override
protected void process(List<Progress> progressList) {
    for (Progress p : progressList){
        System.out.println(p.getTask() + " : " + p.getElement());
    }
}
```

***EDIT: example of UI update***

Here is a slightly modified version of the worker implementation, similar to a sample demonstrated in [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) manual. The only changes are introduction of `textArea` member and updated `setProgress()` call in `doInBackground()`. `progress` property is used to update the progress bar, `process()` is used to update text area.

```
public static class Model extends SwingWorker<Integer, Progress> {

    private HashMap<String, Number> GUIparams;
    private int session;
    private int ticks;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    Model(HashMap<String, Number> KSMParams, JTextArea textArea) {
        GUIparams = KSMParams;
        session = (Integer)GUIparams.get("experimentsInSession");
        ticks = (Integer)GUIparams.get("howManyTicks");

        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Progress> progressList) {
        for (Progress p : progressList){
            textArea.append(p.getTask() + " : " + p.getElement() + "\n");
            System.out.println(p.getTask() + " : " + p.getElement());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Actual simulation
     */
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {

        int i=0;
        while(!isCancelled() && i<session){
            i++;
            int ii=0;
            while(!isCancelled() && ii<ticks){
                // this is n, the task length and I'd like to update the GUI with this value
                ii++;
            }
            //System.out.println(i);
            // this is m, how many time the task has been repeated, and now it is updated in the GUI
            publish(new Progress(i, ii));
            //setProgress(i);
            setProgress(100 * i / session);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return i;
    }  

    /**
     * Invoked when simulation exits
     */
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Experiment session cancelled by user. Closing Session...");
        } else {
            // do stuff

            Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Experiment session ended.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demo initialization:

```
final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
final JButton button = new JButton("Start");

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        HashMap<String, Number> map = Maps.newHashMap();
        map.put("experimentsInSession", 10);
        map.put("howManyTicks", 5);

        Model task = new Model(map, textArea);
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(
                 new PropertyChangeListener() {
                     public  void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                         if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                             progressBar.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
                         }
                     }
                 });
        task.execute();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, just a minor thing: how do I retrieve now the value for the GUI? My code does not work anymore:
if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
    progressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
    showTaskLabel.setText("Experiment " + (Integer) evt.getNewValue() + " concluded.");}

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @SimoneGabbriellini It looks like you're listening to `progress` property. This property is `Integer` and you can use it to update a progress bar as in your comment. To get access to intermediate progress results you should override `process()` method. See my edit for an example.

Comment: Max, I see that your last edit does what I need, thank you very much! Anyway, I have not understood yet how to update my GUI... I have put your code in my SwingWorker, but still the progress property does not listen to that. Can you please give me another hint to connect all the pieces?

Comment: @SimoneGabbriellini I hope my last edit will clarify things a bit. It demos use of `progress` property to update progress bar and `process()` to update text area.

Comment: @Max: thanks a lot for your time and patience, this indeed solves all my doubts!!! All the best, Simo